# How to calculate $\iint_S F\cdot ndS$ over ellipsoid $S$ that is above $z=1$ and given vector field?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vector-fields

> Let $S$ be part of the ellipsoid $3x^2+2y^2+z^2=28$ that is above the plane $z=1$ and $F=\langle yz^2,4xz, zx^2\rangle$ a vector field. Calculate $\iint_S F\cdot ndS$.

I thought of first "closing" the surface $S$ with the plane  $z=1$ and then calculating the integral with Gauss theorem (let the closed surface be $B$) and then calculating separately $\iint F\cdot ndS$ over the plane.

So:
$$
\iint_S F\cdot ndS=\iint_B F\cdot ndS-\iint_{z=1} F\cdot ndS
$$
Calculating $\iint_{z=1} F\cdot ndS$ is relatively easy. The projection (let is be $P$) of $S$ onto the plane is $3x^2+2y^2+1^2=28\iff x^2+y^2=9$, then:
$$
0\le r\le 3\\
0\le \theta\le2\pi\\
n=\langle 0,0,1\rangle\text{  (the normal vector to the projection is essentially the negative axis z)}
$$
Then:
$$
\iint_{P} F\cdot ndS=\iint_P zx^2 dA\stackrel{z=1}{=}\iint_P x^2 dA\stackrel{\text{in polar coord.}}{=}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 r^3\cos^2\theta=\frac{81}{4}\pi.
$$
Link to Wolfram Alpha [calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20int%20r%5E3*cos%5E2(x)%20dr%20dx%20from%20r%3D0%20to%203,%20from%20x%3D0%20to%202pi).

Calculation of $\iint_B F\cdot ndS$ is much more problematic. According to Gauss theorem:
$$
\iint_B F\cdot ndS=\iiint_G\operatorname{div}F \,dv\\
\operatorname{div}F=x^2\implies \iiint_G x^2 \,dv
$$
I thought that we can do the calculation in polar coordinates again:
$$
0\le r\le 3\\
0\le \theta\le2\pi\\
1\le z\le\sqrt{28-3(x^2+y^2)}
$$
Thus:
$$
\iiint_{1}^{\sqrt{28-3r^2}} r^2\cos^2\theta\cdot r 
$$
Very quickly the integral turns ugly but manageable:
$$
\int \cos^2\theta\int \bigg[\frac{r^4}{4}\bigg]^{\sqrt{28-3r^2}}_1=\frac{1}{4}\int \cos^2\theta\int (28-3r^2)^2-1=\\\frac{1}{4}\int \cos^2\theta\int 2862-168r^2+r^4-1=\big(462+\frac{243}{20}-\frac{3}{16}\big)\pi.
$$
So the final answer is:
$$
\iint_S F\cdot ndS=\big(462+\frac{243}{20}-\frac{3}{16}\big)\pi-\frac{81}{4}\pi.
$$
Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $3x^2+2y^2+1=28$ is **not** equivalent to $x^2+y^2=9$.

I suggest to compute the surface integral. To this end let $a$, $b$, $c$ be the semiaxes of the ellipsoid. Then you have a parametric representation of the form
$${\bf r}(\phi,\theta)=\bigl(a\cos\theta\cos\phi,b\cos\theta\sin\phi,c\sin\theta\bigr)\ ,$$
whereby $\phi$ and $\theta$ are GPS coordinates on $S^2$. Now it so happens that $F_1$ is odd in $y$, and $F_2$ is odd in $x$, whereas the normal vector ${\bf r}_\phi\times{\bf r}_\theta$ is even in both $x$ and $y$, by symmetry of the ellipsoid. This implies that from $F\cdot({\bf r}_\phi\times{\bf r}_\theta)$ we only have to compute $$F_3\>({\bf r}_\phi\times{\bf r}_\theta)_3=a^2c\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\cos^2\phi\cdot ab\cos\theta\sin\theta\ .$$
Now you have to integrate this over $0\leq\phi\leq2\pi$ and over $\theta_1\leq\theta\leq{\pi\over2}$, whereby $\theta_1$ is defined by the condition $c\sin\theta_1=1$. Since $\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2\phi\>d\phi=\pi$ we obtain in this way
$$\Phi=\pi a^3bc \int_{\theta_1}^{\pi/2}\cos^3\theta\sin^2\theta\>d\theta\ .$$
Here the last integral can be written as
$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\pi/2}(\sin^2\theta-\sin^4\theta)\>\cos\theta\>d\theta=\int_{\sin \theta_1}^1(u^2-u^4)\>du\ ,$$
which simplifies matters considerably.